# Xcode Swift 3 Consecutive declarations on line must be separated by ; build error

Tags: ios, xcode, build, tvos

I have created an Xcode project which has 2 targets (iOS and tvOS).
I want to create a button class which I use on all the scenes throughout each target.

Outside of the two projects I create a myButton.swift file and check the target box for both.

Initially it builds correctly.  However, when I add the following lines to the swift file I get the build error:

```
public class myButton : SKSpriteNode {
var j:Int = 0;

fileprivate class Record {

}
```

}

The build errors are:
/Users/jer_mac/Documents/WaitingOnAces2/myButton.swift:12:5: Expected declaration
/Users/jer_mac/Documents/WaitingOnAces2/myButton.swift:12:16: Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
/Users/jer_mac/Documents/WaitingOnAces2/myButton.swift:9:25: Use of undeclared type 'SKSpriteNode'

Using only one of the targets (tvOS) works, but if I check the iOS target it does not build.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you importing SpriteKit?

Comment: Whether it's a failure to `import SpriteKit` or some other error earlier in your code, the "must be separated" message is a red herring. The only conclusion I would draw from this error is that the compiler is just having trouble making sense of the code. I cannot produce those precise errors using your code snippet, so the problem probably rests elsewhere. I'd suggest you figure out the precise steps necessary to reproduce that problem starting with a blank project and edit your question to include that [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The error mentioned in your title (`Consecutive declarations on line must be separated by ;` differs from the error in your question (`Use of undeclared type 'SKSpriteNode'`).

The later can be fixed by importing `SpriteKit`. The following code (yours) compiles fine:

```
import SpriteKit
public class myButton : SKSpriteNode {
    var j = 0;
    fileprivate class Record {

    }
}
```